# Algorithm to find a minimal normal subgroup of given group $G$ by matrix group representation

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, normal-subgroups, algebraic-complexity

Given a matrix group $G$ by its generators i.e. $G =\langle A_1,A_2,...,A_k \rangle \leq GL_n(q)$, where each $A_i$'s are matrix in $GL_n(q)$

> **Q.** Does there exist a polynomial time (polynomial in input size) algorithm to find a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ if it exists otherwise it returns $G$ is simple?

There is an algorithm when group is given by permutation representation. Kindly share any reference if there is such algorithm for matrix group representation.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I don’t understand the formulation of the question (I think you mean G to be finite?), but if you consider the 1-dimensional case of a root of unity, this is equivalent to factorization, which is not known to have a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: I have edited a question. $G$ is finite. What do you mean by a factorization and how this is equivalent to it?

Comment: The subgroups of $\langle e^{2πi/n}\rangle$ correspond to m|n. So finding normal subgroups is equivalent to factorization of n.

Comment: @IanAgol However, the problem factorization asks for an algorithm that factorizes $n$ in $O(log(n)^k)$ time, not $O(n^k)$ (which is trivially possible). So an important question here is : "Polynomial *in what*?" (As an aside: Is the permutation group algorithm really polynomial??)

Comment: @JohannesHahn Polynomial in input size. Edited the question.      Yes, There is a polynomial time (poly in input size, which is $n \log n$ )algorithm to find a minimal normal subgroup when the input group is given by Permutation representation.

Comment: @JohannesHahn I am sure this is the standard meaning of polynomial-time, meaning polynomial in size of input. Ian Agol is essentially correct, to calculate the order of a matrix in ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ you need to be able to factorize $q^n-1$, which is not known to be polynomial-time. You also need a discrete log oracle to have any chance of an affirmative answer. And yes, the permuation group algorithm is really poynomial. You can identify the composition factors of a subgroup of $S_n$ in polynomial time.

Comment: By the way, if $G$ is simple then $G$ is itself a minimal normal subgroup. All nontrivial finite groups have minimal normal subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper

```
Holt, D., Leedham-Green, C. R., & O'Brien EA (2020). Constructing composition factors for a linear group in polynomial time. JOURNAL OF ALGEBRA, 561, 215-236. 10.1016/j.jalgebra.2020.02.018
```

the authors consider the question of finding a composition series of a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ - I think that finding a minimal normal subgroup is of the same difficulty.

There is lots of earlier literature on this topic: Babai and various co-authors have made many theoretical contributions. The paper by Holt, Leedham-Green and O'Brien is geared more towards finding practical algorithms, and the $\mathtt{CompositionTree}$ function in Magma is very effective and improving all the time.

To have any chance of an affirmative answer to the question, you need to assume the availability of certain oracles. If your group is a cyclic subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ of order dividing $q^n-1$, then you need to be able to factorize $q^n-1$ to proceed. There are also simple examples of subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2n,q)$ in which you need a discrete log oracle to decide whether the given group is $C_p$ or $C_p \times C_p$ for a prime $p$ dividing $q^n-1$.

The current situation is that, subject to the availability of certain oracles, there is a polynomial-time Las Vegas algorithm to find a composition series of the group provided that it has no composition factors isomorphic to $^2B_2(2^{2k+1})$, $^2F_4(2^{2k+1})$, $^3D_4(2^k)$, or $^2G_2(3^{2k+1})$ for any $k$.

The problem with these families of exceptional groups is that there is currently no known polynomial-time constructive recognition algorithm, and it is to be hoped that this situation will be remedied in the future. But the case  $^2G_2(3^{2k+1})$ (Ree groups) looks particularly challenging.

Incidentally, the need for the oracles rarely if ever results in bottlenecks in practical calculations, mainly because of the amount of effort that has gone into finding effective implementations of the discrete log and integer factorization problems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am wondering why you thought that 'finding a minimal normal subgroup is of the same difficulty as finding composition series?'

Comment: I am asking this because generally Chief series is related to minimal normal subgroup and not composition series. And there is known algorithm to compute a chief series in matrix group e.g. this paper    http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/papers/csmatgp/csmatgp.pdf.

Comment: The paper was based on work and programs written by a former research student of mine,and unfortunately after he got his PhD he left for more lucrative employment, so that whole project, which was based on aiming for a chief series from the beginning was never developed further, which was a pity. At the moment, there is a Magma function $\mathtt{LMGChiefSeries}$ that uses the output of $\mathtt{CompositionTree}$ to compute a chief series. I think it is polynomial-time subject to the same restrictions as $\mathtt{CompositionTree}$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. I was thinking that there is a polynomial time algorithm to compute chief series for any given matrix group but it is clear now.